# How to compare two tsv extract in Unix and print differences with key and header?

Tags: text-processing, diff

I have two files with same header and structure and the first column is a key.

File 1:

```
key    val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
Item1  10   12   44   88   22
Item2  33   33   43   77   22
Item3  28   44   55   22   11
Item4  12   55   55   14   44
```

File2:

```
key    val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
Item1  10   11   44   99   22
Item2  33   33   43   77   22
Item3  28   44   55   22   11
Item4  12   55   55   14   00
```

As you noticed in above file, there are two differences in the files:

- val2 and val4 of item1 is different
- val5 of item 4 is different

So I would like to produce a comparison output which should tell me which fields of which item are different. The output should be something similar to :

```
Item1: val2,val4
Item4: val5
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting, look at other questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples, and then [edit] your question to fix your formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
awk -v ref=file1 '
    {
        getline refline <ref

        if (NR == 1) split(refline, head)

        nf = split(refline, a)

        for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
            if ($i != a[i])
                diffcol[++n] = i

        if (n > 0) {
            $0 = a[1]

            for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
                $(i+1) = head[diffcol[i]]

            print
            n = 0
        }
    }' file2
```

This compares your `file2` against the "reference file" `file1`.  The lines from `file2` is read as ordinarily done by `awk`, while the lines from `file1` are explicitly read by calling `getline` in the `awk` code and splitting them with `split`.

The `split(refline, head)` block sets the `head` array to the headers, read from `file1`.  This is only executed for the first line of input from `file2`.

The first loop compares the fields between the two files and the column number of any field that is different and appended to the `diffcol` array.

If one or several differences were found, the first field of `file1` will be outputted followed by the headers of the fields (from `file1`) that were different.

The way I have written the code, the header line and the first field are also subject to the comparison, so if a difference is found in the first field, you'll get a line of output for that too, probably with `key` at the start of the line (as that's the first field's value in `file1`).

The code does not assume that the number of columns are the same in the two files.

Given the data in your question, you would get the following output from this code:

```
Item1 val2 val4
Item4 val5
```

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of `paste` and `awk`, assuming all records have the same number of fields:

```
paste file1 file2 |
  awk -F'\t' '
    NR == 1 {cols = split($0, hdr) / 2; next}
    {
      diff = sep = ""
      for (i = 2; i <= cols; i++)
        if ($i "" != $(i+cols) "") {
          diff = diff sep hdr[i]
          sep = ","
        }
      if (sep) print $1": "diff
    }'
```

We append `""` to each side of the `!=` comparison so the comparison be always lexical (`0` be different from `00` or `-0`, `inf` from `infinity`, 1e500, etc). Remove those for the comparison to be numerical when the fields look like numbers.